# How to stop the text to change(flexible Padding) inside div while width and height are being decreased

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div inside another div. Child div contain some text. when i apply animation. decrease width and height the text Inside gets reset according to the size. I understand why this happen but i want to stop the text to change its look.

```js
function animation() {
  $(".outer").animate({
    "width": "200px",
    "height": "300px"
  });
}
animation();
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div > div {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div>
    Hello world Hello world hello world
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When/where are you calling `animation()`? Also note you're missing a `:` in your CSS

Comment: I know that but i only want just keep the text look same as it.. As it don't look good the text to resize during animation :)

Comment: If you don't want the text layout to change, you need to preserve the layout of its container div. The easiest way would be by setting an explicit width that's equal to its starting width (i.e. before .animate() is run). However that would cause it to break outside the container, is that your intention?

Comment: Ya you got it! but whole problem is about the padding: 30px

Comment: If you any idea you can provide me some sample code

Comment: I got a idea what to do tnx for the providing base idea. I have to use css inside div with absolute position and left 0 right 0 top 0 and height 0, so that it will be in centre at any cost. :) this is the solution.

Comment: I find the solution

Comment: The solution is using with above absolute trick work fine

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, try to add `min-width: 300px;` to the `div > div` selector.
Since you want to reduce the container with the animation, you may want to add `overflow: scroll;` on the `.outer` DIV.

Comment: tnx for adding some more idea for the solution!